# Python Regular expression matching integer after a tab

Tags: python, regex

How can I match an integer written after a tab? What is the regular expression for that?

I have tried this:

```
line = '0     1'
re.match('\t+\d',line)
```

But this does not work - 1 is not matched.

I want 1 to be matched and returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your regex is failing is that the tab is actually four spaces. If the string is really more complex than your example, you can use `\s+` to match one or more whitespace characters ( any of `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`):

```
import re
line = "0     1"
print re.findall("\s+(\d+)", line)
```

which prints

```
['1']
```

If your string *isn't* more complex than your example, you can use vks' solution and match only the digits (`"\d+$"`).

Answer (score 2):

```
\d+$
```

You can simply use this instead.Also use `re.findall` instead of `match` as `match` matches from `beginning`.

```
line = '0     1'
re.findall(r'\d+$',line,re.M)
```

Comment: Hah, seems he forgot. Here, have one of mine!

Comment: @EvenLisle guess he cant seeing his reputation :)

Comment: Oh, right. Well, it's the thought etc. Good thing I upvoted then.

Answer (score 1):

`re.match` only matches at the start of the line:

```
>>> line='0\t1'
>>> print(line)
0   1
>>> re.match(r'\t(\d+)', line)          # no match...
```

You want `re.search` instead:

```
>>> re.search(r'\t(\d+)', line)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 3), match='\t1'>
>>> re.search(r'\t(\d+)', line).group(1)
'1'
```